# How to get light and shadows to overlay certain colors?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, shadows

I'm working on a 3D style that emulates my illustration style. Example:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to make shadows apply a purple shade (mulitply) and a yellow for highlights (add). [I know the Mix Node has different Blend modes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/color/mix.html), but I have no clue how to apply those certain colors to the natural shadows a light source would cast.

Any idea how I would do this?

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Okay, I figured out how to add the shadow at least using a node setup like this, but I'm totally lost on how to add the highlights to this (as a yellow color)

https://imgur.com/a/Pr7LlzC

Comment: Hello and welcome. Glad you figured it out, you should post that as an answer below with a short explanation of the techniques used and how to achieve it

Comment: Hey Duarte. It isn't fully figured out. I did post the node in a screenshot to get the shading to work, but still haven't figured out how to get a shader working to simulate the highlighting.